# Harvesting COM+ Instance Statistics in C# or PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell, com+

I have several COM+ applications, each with several components and running instances. I can look at the Component Services management applet to see statistics (call time, pooled, activated, in call, etc.). I'd like to get programmatic access to this same information so I can write a monitoring tool to send alerts if things get backed up.

Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a C# API or PowerShell script that provides actual instance information. I can get all kinds of information about the actual application, and it's constituent components, just nothing about the running instances.

I've seen [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd179218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that talks about "COM+ Tracking", and it sounds like exactly what I need, but I'm not sure how to translate that to C#.

I've also successfully used PS to get to the COM+ Administration Collections, but the ["ApplicationInstances" collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) doesn't contain anything about actual metrics.

Any ideas? Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289138%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [code sample](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/0/1/00106a07-29ef-4a76-a689-a0007501b736/COMPlusMon.exe) which pretty much answers my questions.

Note that in order to install the code sample, I had to manually extract the contents from the installer using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org). The installer itself would throw an error when running on Windows 7 for some reason.

I haven't completed yet, but I expect to be able to modify this solution to use the COM+ Tracking interfaces (namely the [IComTrackingInfoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686099%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface), which provides the granularity and information I need (call durations, etc.)